# textArea can not be resolved java

Tags: java, swing, textarea, mouseevent, jtextarea

```
    public Aufgabezwei() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            textArea1.append(e);

        }
    });
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea();
    textArea1.setText("Willkommen");
    textArea1.setBounds(111, 11, 182, 127);

    contentPane.add(textArea1);
}
```

Why do I get the error textArea1 can not be reslved at the mouseclicked event ? 
And how can I fix it ?

Comment: You look to be using a local variable **before** you've declared and initialized it. There's got to be a duplicate for this question somewhere.

Comment: isn t it declared as JTextArea ?

Comment: But look ***WHERE*** it's declared -- it's **after** you use it!

Comment: Just move the declaration above `contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {`...

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you shouldn't be using Swing unless you're forced to. JavaFX is much nicer to use, Swing is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

This line is where you declare the variable `textArea1`:

```
JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea();
```

You are trying to use it before you declare it, which is not allowed for local variables in Java.

Move this declaration above the mouse listener creation to make it available to it.